# Cannot convert value of type NSMutableDictionary? to expected argument type [NSObject: AnyObject]!

Tags: ios, google-analytics, swift3

i wanted to jump over to use Xcode 8 beta and convert my code, but I'm facing some kind of problem here, i am using Google Analytics SDK to send events,and this is how i used to use it in Swift 2.2 :

```
    let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker?.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "ViewController")
    let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
    tracker?.send(builder?.build() as [NSObject:AnyObject])
```

But now i want to use Swift 3, its telling me :

> Cannot convert value of type NSMutableDicationary to type [NSObject :
>   AnyObject] in coercion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to make a variable to hold your `NSMutableDictionary` then pass it to `send()` method.

```
let dictionary = (builder?.build())! as NSMutableDictionary
tracker?.send(dictionary as [NSObject: AnyObject]!)
```

**UPDATE:** Another clean way to use in Swift 3

```
guard let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker else { return }
tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "ViewController")
guard let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView() else { 
return }
tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject:AnyObject])
```

Comment: or: tracker?.send(((builder?.build())! as NSMutableDictionary) as [NSObject: AnyObject]!)

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve the issue. It is always good to unwrap optionals before use them directly, Otherwise you may regret later.

```
 if let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker, builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
 {                
    if let dict = builder.build(), mutableDict = dict as [NSObject: AnyObject]?
     {
       tracker.send( mutableDict )
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 3**

**for screen tracking use below code**

```
    func trackScreen(screenName:String){  
            let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker     
            tracker?.set(kGAIScreenName, value: screenName) 
            let builder:NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build()      
            tracker?.send(builder as! [NSObject:AnyObject]) 
         }
```

**for event Tracking**

```
func eventTracking(){
    let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    let builder:NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent(
    withCategory:"categoryName",
    action:"ok button Clicked",
    label:"button name",
    value:nil).build()
    tracker?.send(builder as! [NSObject:AnyObject])
    }
```